# jQuery Mobile 1.4+ pagecontainerbeforechange bug?

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

I am experimenting with the new way of handling page events in jqM and have run into a curious issue.  When handling the pagecontainerbeforechange event

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforechange',function(e,u){test(e,u,'changing');})

function test(e,u,msg){console.log($(u.toPage));}
```

Attempting to put a jQuery object wrapper around u.toPage - as done above - produces strange behavior.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egn7g5xb/1/) to see what I mean

- Click on the Second Page button and then view the console.  Nothing will happen (the second page is not shown) and you will see a message along the lines of *Uncaught error:syntax error, unrecognized expression http://jsfiddle.net/egn7g5xb/1/show/#second
- Now comment out Line 7 and run the fiddle again.  No such issue this time and the second page gets shown.

Perhaps someone here might be able to explain what is going on here?

Comment: That's because the toPage object is already a jQuery object. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforechange  You don't need to wrap it.

Comment: It fired twice, first time it returns a string, second time an object. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/pagecontainerbeforechange/

Comment: @ezanker - you may well have a point but not doing the wrap makes no difference.  See my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egn7g5xb/3/).  If you comment out line 4 the second page shows up ok.  If it is uncommented nothing happens & you get the error http://jsfiddle.net/_display/#second uncaught type error : undefined is not a function

Comment: @Omar, I wish it were that easy.  Take a look at my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egn7g5xb/4/).  Check out the console.  As you will see while pagecontentbeforechange is being fired twice u.toPage is a jQuery object for both instances.  What is interesting is that u.toPage is different for the change event.  Any insights here?

Comment: The very first run, both times it returns an object. Afterwards, it returns string and then object http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/egn7g5xb/7/

Comment: `Uncaught error:syntax error, unrecognized expression` because you're converting a _string_ into jQuery object http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/egn7g5xb/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On initial run, jQuery Mobile creates a *fake page* before navigating to *first page* in DOM. At that stage, `pagecontainerbeforechange` fires twice and returns `.toPage` as an `object`.

Later on, upon navigating to other pages, it fires twice again; however, it returns a `string` first time (URL/hash) and second time it returns an `object` which is the *page* itself.

Therefore, when using that event, you have to determine whether `.toPage` is an `object` or a `string`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
  if (typeof data.toPage == "string") {
    /* parse url */
  }

  if (typeof data.toPage == "object") {
    /* manipulate page navigating to */
  }
});
```

Note that `pagecontainerbeforetransition` is similar to `beforechange`, however, it fires once and returns `.toPage` as an `object`.

Comment: Are You aware of the reason behind the behavior pointed out in your first sentence? Is there any way to distinguish between these two `pagecontainerbeforechange` events *on first run*? Sadly, as You said, both events returns `.toPage` as an object. I need to trap just only the last one.

Comment: @deblocker I really forgot how jQM works lol. I haven't touched code in long time. Try manual initializing of the framework on `mobileinit`. I'm sorry my friend.

Answer (score 1):

First, create your pagecontainer events within $(document).on("pagecreate", "#first", function(){ .. }).

Then the selector for these events should be $(":mobile-pagecontainer") or $("body") NOT $(document).

```
function test(e,u,msg)
{
    console.log(msg); 
    var IsJQ = u.toPage instanceof $;
    console.log(IsJQ);   
    if (IsJQ){
        console.log(u.toPage.data());   
    } else {
        console.log(u.toPage);
    }
    console.log('---');   
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#first", function(){
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on('pagecontainerbeforechange', function (e, u) {
        test(e,u,'changing');
    });
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on('pagecontainerchange',function(e,u){
        test(e,u,'changed');
    });

});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/egn7g5xb/5/)**